# Store Data on Users Google Account

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have used [This](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to create a login on my site, with the `onSignIn` function, `signOut` function, and `auth2.isSignedIn.get()` function (which checks if you are already signed in).

Now is there a way if which I can get a piece of data from the site, e.g. a special value from an input that the user has typed, and store it on the user (google user who logged in)'s google account, preferably as a key, like localStorage?

A minor start here:

```js
document.getElementById("userText").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var data = document.getElementById("userText").value;
    
    googleAccount.userData = data; // Change this Line
});
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "userText">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, it's just not within the goals and purposes of an(y) authentication provider.

Have you thought of:

- How would Google keep "your" piece of data secure and separate from other sites that would try to do the same for that user?
- How would Google deal with the possibly Gigabytes of data that it would have to store (per user, for multiple sites combined) within days after this feature would be introduced?

The way this is usually done is by **creating a database / datastore**, that you then **maintain** and **make backups of** (and possibly **pay for**) in which you store data for each user, using some User ID as a "key".

Comment: Are there any simple databases that don't require any back-end coding that you would recommend?

Comment: You can try [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) that can be [free or paid](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). I have not personally used it from javascript. You would certainly need to figure out how to securely connect from a browser. See the [examples page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples) and filter it by "Web" (samples for Web are denoted by a red **`</>`** symbol).